# Is there something like acceleration constraint in a rigid body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, rigid-body-dynamics, constrained-dynamics

Suppose we have two points on a body which having acceleration a1 and a2 direction we know and magnitude as well , is there some sort of relation between them we can establish , like for velocities along the line joining velocities must be same sort of ? For example a rod which has two points of acceleration value known and directions too suppose angle theta1 for a1 and theta 2 for a2 from the rod , is there a constraint which can be established on that ? As we know velocity along the line joining the rod should be same everywhere , otherwise it fails to consider rigid body . Hope now clarity is given

[image: FIGURE IS HERE]

[is there some relation between them which we can deduce thats what i am asking ] body is just intially has such acc vectors , so intiallly angulsr velocity is zero so not shown in figure

Comment: Question is not clear, explain with any diagram or give a detailed elaboration about the situation otherwise it's a bit harder to understand.

Comment: Always diagram is not needed , imagine just a rod for example with two point known accelerations.

Comment: I can't make out what you are asking. At a minimum, include a diagram.

Comment: Given Sir now ..

Comment: Just a vectorial sum of the acceleration. It will give you the real accelaration

Comment: Photo added thanks John Alexiou Sir , may anyone who voted to close please remove it , i hope now its understandable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there is. All velocities/accelerations on the extended rigid body are a result of the same motion of the rigid body, which we refer to as the rotating frame.

Just as the velocities of two points on a rigid body are related by $$ \boldsymbol{v}_A + \boldsymbol{r}_A \times \boldsymbol{\omega} = \boldsymbol{v}_B + \boldsymbol{r}_B \times \boldsymbol{\omega}$$

where $\boldsymbol{r}_A$ is the position vector of point **A**, $\boldsymbol{r}_B$ the position vector of point **B**, $\boldsymbol{v}_A$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_B$ the velocity vectors of the points, and $\boldsymbol{\omega}
$ the rotationa velocity *of the rigid body*.

Take the time derivative of the above using the chain rule to get

$$ \boldsymbol{a}_A + \boldsymbol{r}_A \times \boldsymbol{\dot \omega} + \boldsymbol{v}_A \times \boldsymbol{\omega} = \boldsymbol{a}_B + \boldsymbol{r}_B \times \boldsymbol{\dot \omega} + \boldsymbol{v}_A \times \boldsymbol{\omega}$$

Which is the kinematic constraint between two points. The above is commonly rewritten as follows, using the relative position vector $\boldsymbol{d} = \boldsymbol{r}_A - \boldsymbol{r}_B$

$$\boldsymbol{v}_A = \boldsymbol{v}_B + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{d}$$
$$\boldsymbol{a}_A = \boldsymbol{a}_B + \boldsymbol{\dot \omega} \times \boldsymbol{d} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times ( \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{d}) $$

Comment: Thanks Sir now understood :)